# Replace in a string with a numeric function in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I have a string vector:

```
vec<-c("0","[0.046-0.112)","[0.112-0.141)","[0.141-0.177)","[0.177-0.206)",">=0.206")
```

I'd like to transform the decimal numbers inside this character vector in percent numbers. I usually use the package `stingr` to elab text with `regex`. So my idea is a thing like:

```
str_replace_all(vec, "([0-9.]{5})", paste(as.numeric("\\1")*100,"%") )
```

this is what I'd like to expect:

```
"0%" "[4.6%-11.2%)" "[11.2%-14.1%)" "[14.1%-17.7%)" "[17.7%-20.6%)" ">20.6%"
```

but this is my output

```
[1] "0"           "[NA %-NA %)" "[NA %-NA %)" "[NA %-NA %)" "[NA %-NA %)"
[6] ">=NA %"     
Warning message:
In paste(round(as.numeric("\\1") * 100, 1), "%") :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('[0-9.]+', ~ paste0(100*as.numeric(x), '%'), vec)
#[1] "0%"            "[4.6%-11.2%)"  "[11.2%-14.1%)" "[14.1%-17.7%)"
#[5] "[17.7%-20.6%)" ">=20.6%"
```